# Any good reason to study graphic design?

Tags: education

I would like to know for people that studied graphic design what is a good argument and reason to study that career, and what are the benefits of it.
I want to study this career but also would like to do an engineering, is it really necessary to study graphic design?
I guess sometimes you can learn graphic design by reading from contemporary designers like Picasso and reading modern books.

So what are your arguments and opinions for studying this career, and what are your experiences?

Comment: Possible duplicate??? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/what-does-an-artist-who-wants-to-learn-graphic-design-need-to-know?rq=1

Comment: Hello and wellcome, you might want to edit your question a bit. Right now the question comes out very negative which some people might feel offensive. The question if fine but could be framed a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a graphics designer, but I can answer the part about you can learn this in books part.

It is possible to learn everything from books alone. Period. Even all the info I learned in university studying for my master's in mechanical engineering could have been learned from books alone. Its possible, but not feasible.

A good education will accelerate the process. It will also open you to a wider world view in a way that you might not otherwise explore. Every profession has lots of convolution, even if its in theory simple. Just because humans have been doing it for a while. So theres always lots of things you should familiarize yourself with.

Remember a true expert knows several alternative methods to accomplish things. This knowledge can really make a huge difference. However, knowing  how something is done is not the same thing as knowing how to do it. You still need practice. The school provides practice in a environment that's less serious than work but more demanding than most of us can muster.

On top of this you forget is that the diploma may count arbitrarily for some jobs. Useful or not. So for example if I wanted to work in higher positions it may be mandatory by policy to demonstrate a degree.

Answer (score 0):

As a Graphic Designer, studying the subject didn't just make my designs better, it made me better. It gave me confidence, the mentality, and taught me how to present myself when presenting work. You could be a wiz at designing, but how to talk to clients, how to present well, and how convey your ideas is something I picked up through lectures. I used to mumble, and shuffle my way through presentations when I first started university. And it also taught me to take so much nonsense of people who have a problem with your design. My peers had the confidence to tell me how bad or how good they really thought it was. It taught me about print specifications, gave me inspiration, and had the pleasure of working alongside other designers who wanted the same as me, to succeed in a saturated industry that changes by the months.

So Yes, I do think studying Graphic Design is a good reason.