# What skills are necessary and/or recommended to become a graphic designer

Tags: drawing

I am planning to major in Graphic Design, but I am unsure if it is the right choice for me.
I would like to know what skills I should know before starting to study it so I can get a head start.
One particular skill I am confused on is drawing.  I have read online that drawing is a non-essential skill for graphic design, but on some cases I have also read that some drawing skill is required.

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to GD.SE! We have [this similar question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/must-one-have-a-knowledge-of-fine-art-to-be-a-graphic-designer-should-all-graph) that talks exactly about the drawing component of GD. You can also check our [highest rated questions tagged with "designer"](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designers?sort=votes&pagesize=15), there are some really good ones there! Anything that is not covered by those, you can ask as a new question.

Comment: And finally, [this is our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot), where you can ask designers directly :)

Comment: Here's a related question with some good answers: [How would I know how good of a designer I am?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13808/how-would-i-know-how-good-of-a-designer-i-am)