# Photoshop skills are not great

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I'm a entry-level graphic designer. My skills in Illustrator and Indesign are pretty strong but my skills in Photoshop are not great and I have no drawing skills either. Will this affect my career?

Comment: Hi Bianca! I'm not sure if this can be answered categorically. My response would be: "It depends". Plus, if you already know Illustrator you could learn Photoshop in a week :) So, will it affect your career? If you look for a position that requires PS right now, yes. The drawing skills question is, I think, more answerable. I recall we have some similar ones, let me see what I can find.

Comment: Here: [Must one have a knowledge of fine art to be a Graphic Designer? Should all Graphic Designers know how to draw?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/must-one-have-a-knowledge-of-fine-art-to-be-a-graphic-designer-should-all-graph/1521#1521)

Answer (score 1):

I would use this opportunity then to get better. Go online, do tutorials, play around in the program. In the long run you will find that you are stuck in your career or without a career if you are not well-rounded.

Good luck! And remember, if you run into problems you can always come here to ask, learning from others is always useful with programs such as these. Create a community around you and just keep pushing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will affect your career.

Any absence of talent or skills will impact your career.  Just as a great sprinter unable to jump hurdles is limited to flat races.

Employment is not "equal opportunity" in terms of ability, talents, experience, resourcefulness and dedication.

The more talents and skills you have, combined with the greater experience and your resourcefulness and dedication, the more opportunities you have.

Everything less needs to be accepted, or you need to compensate by being stronger in some other area sufficiently to overcome the weakness in your talents and/or skills.

The more resourceful and dedicated you are the more opportunities will present by virtue of where you are and what you're doing.

HOWEVER, at the ends of all things, no amount of alternative values will make up for missing talents.

Nobody is going to want you to do cartoon drawings if you can't illustrate, regardless of experience, other talents etc.