# Can you be a graphic design major but not have the ability to draw?

Tags: drawing, advertising

I have never really had the ability to draw, but I've also never taken a formal drawing class.  I am interested in graphic design and doing advertisements.  Do you need strong drawing skills to major in graphic design?

Comment: Welcome Carly! I edited your question to correct the grammar. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Scott just likes ruining my bad jokes :(

Comment: No, but it certainly helps, and any good program will help you along with that regardless (find a program with a strong fine arts component)

Comment: My answer would be yes, you need to have basic drawing skills. This questions takes up the same question, you might find the answers helpful: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/must-one-have-a-knowledge-of-fine-art-to-be-a-graphic-designer-should-all-graph

Comment: You allmost cettainly know how to draw. Most people who claim they can not draw, can draw and have in fact known how to do it since the age of two years old. Your just not confident at it which is fine. That can be overcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a fan of storing socks either. But kidding aside, it is okay. Depending on the program you can certainly do advertising without being able to draw, that's what I do professionally. I didn't even study graphic design. You just have to realize your strengths and weaknesses and understand that it will limit the prospects. If a company wants a graphic designer that can do illustrations you shouldn't waste your time applying. If you excel at branding or concept then you'll end up focusing on that and it's limiting, but its not completely insurmountable. You could always spend some time while in graphic design school focusing on drawing in courses and your free time to strengthen your weaknesses. It always hard to get yourself to strengthen something you're not good at but its also very, very rewarding when you make it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have the ability to draw, what you need though is good visual imagination and sense of aesthetics.

Obviously you should be able to sketch so that you can visualize your ideas to customers and your bosses quickly, but sketches can be really loose so most likely you will do just fine.